# Changing animations from animate.css to Angular animations

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I am learning to use the Angular animations, before I was using animate.css but is giving me some delays in a certain elements so I want to try with ng-animate. Just an example, this is the div that I am trying to animate with the classes `animated bounceInRight` which are the ones from animate.css, so, how can I do to apply the angular animations instead of animate.css that you see there ?

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sports">
      <div class="animated bounceInRight"
           ng-if="sport.leagues.length">

            ...

          </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "delays in certain elements"?  What are you trying to do with AngularJS' `ng-animate` that `Animate.css` isn't doing?

Comment: I have an message appearing each time that an array is empty, when that message appears is nice with animate.css, but when the array is filled out again, that message must disappear immediately, but it takes around 2 seconds and then leaves

Comment: and that's something happening not only with that elements, it happens with all the elements that apply that animate.css classes.